# slideup once click slidedown div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done slideup and slidedown div using jquery. Here i have three boxes.Once we click the head, the content will open. then click another head, that content will open and old content close. But i cont close same content. All time any one of the content is open. I need once we click head that content need to close.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    var parent = $this.closest('.acc');
    $("p").removeClass('open');
    $this.addClass('open');
    $('.acc-body').slideUp();
    parent.find('.acc-body').slideDown();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.acc {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

.acc-head {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

.acc-head.open {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.acc-body {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="max-width: 500px;">
  <div class="acc">
    <p class="acc-head">
      head
    </p>
    <div class="acc-body">
      Learn by examples! At W3Schools you will find a lot of jQuery examples to edit and test yourself.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="acc">
    <p class="acc-head">
      head
    </p>
    <div class="acc-body">
      Learn by examples! At W3Schools you will find a lot of jQuery examples to edit and test yourself.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="acc">
    <p class="acc-head">
      head
    </p>
    <div class="acc-body">
      Learn by examples! At W3Schools you will find a lot of jQuery examples to edit and test yourself.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix this use `slideToggle()` on `.acc-body`, and use `not()` to exclude it from the `slideUp()`. The same pattern works for adding and removing the `open` class on the `p` elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $target = $this.next();
    
    $("p").not($this).removeClass('open');
    $this.toggleClass('open');
    
    $('.acc-body').not($target).slideUp();
    $target.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.acc {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

.acc-head {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

.acc-head.open {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.acc-body {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="max-width: 500px;">
  <div class="acc">
    <p class="acc-head">
      head
    </p>
    <div class="acc-body">
      Learn by examples! At W3Schools you will find a lot of jQuery examples to edit and test yourself.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="acc">
    <p class="acc-head">
      head
    </p>
    <div class="acc-body">
      Learn by examples! At W3Schools you will find a lot of jQuery examples to edit and test yourself.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="acc">
    <p class="acc-head">
      head
    </p>
    <div class="acc-body">
      Learn by examples! At W3Schools you will find a lot of jQuery examples to edit and test yourself.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just look first for the head owning the class `open`.

Fixed it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("p").click(function(){
            $this = $(this);
            if($this.hasClass('open')){
                $this.removeClass('open');
                $this.siblings('.acc-body').slideUp();
            }else{
                var parent = $this.closest('.acc');
                $("p").removeClass('open');
                $this.addClass('open');
                $('.acc-body').slideUp();
                parent.find('.acc-body').slideDown();
            }
        });
    });
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution for You!!!

Using Jquery hasClass() function we can solve this problem. First we need to check clicked element has class or not. if has 'open' class then do the slideup function, else do the slideDown function.and remove all open class for other 'p'.

we solve this function using slideToggle() also.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("p").click(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  if($this.hasClass('open')){
    $this.removeClass('open');
    $('.acc-body').slideUp();
  }else{ 
    var parent = $this.closest('.acc');
    $('p').removeClass('open');
    $this.addClass('open')
    $('.acc-body').slideUp();
    parent.find('.acc-body').slideDown();
 }; 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

 body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.acc{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}
.acc-head{
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #ccc;
}
.acc-head.open{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.acc-body{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: none;
}

</style>


<div style="max-width: 500px;">
<div class="acc">
    <p class="acc-head">
        head1
    </p>
    <div class="acc-body">
        Learn by examples! At W3Schools you will find a lot of jQuery examples to edit and test yourself.
    </div>
</div>


<div class="acc">
    <p class="acc-head">
        head2
    </p>
    <div class="acc-body">
        Learn by examples! At W3Schools you will find a lot of jQuery examples to edit and test yourself.
    </div>
</div>


<div class="acc">
    <p class="acc-head">
        head3
    </p>
    <div class="acc-body">
        Learn by examples! At W3Schools you will find a lot of jQuery examples to edit and test yourself.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Sure @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple Accordion:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">Section 1</div>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion">Section 2</div>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion">Section 3</div>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to [copy code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) I'd suggest W3Schools is about the last place you'd want to copy considering the low standards of some of their example.

Comment: Yes Its fine for me.